# Creating a Google App signing PEM from Xamarin Keystore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-keystore

I tried to provide a PEM file to Google so that they can re-key the app signing in Google Console.

This is the command they want me to use:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore MYALIAS.keystore
```

However, I want to use the Keystore in Xamarin so that I can continue to publish, archive, and sign through Visual Studio. If I make a new pair with their command, can I only sign using the Android Studio tools?

So I removed the genkeypair tried this:

```
keytool -export -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -alias MYALIAS -file MYALIAS.pem -keystore MYALIAS.keystore
```

But, they said that the PEM was not compatible.

What keytool command can I use to keep using my Xamarin keystore while meeting Google's requirements?

Do I need to include the genkeypair if I want to keep using the Xamarin keystore?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "Xamarin" a keystore is a not Xamarin specific. Removing the Xamarin tag.

Comment: Have tried to follow these guides [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows#newcertvs)?

Comment: Yes, I have done both of those. I have the keystore file, but now I must export out a PEM that meets google's requirements so that they have the private key in their records too.